# Rerun getToken(authorization) requests only on expiry - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My testplan is as follows:

- get token: requests to get access token

  - Setting a user defined variable to get the **tokenGeneratedTime**, let's say tokenGeneratedTime to `${__time(,)}`
- Check if token is expired(if controller) - `{__jexl3((${__time(,)} - ${tokenGenerationTime}) > 3599000)}`

  - if true, goes to get token sampler
  - if false, goes to subsequent requests
- Some https requests

So if I run this test plan for the first time(only 1 iteration), request to get token is fired, the condition would be evaluated as false and the subsequent requests are fired. All is well and good. But as you can see, if I run the test plan again immediately(not iterating) for the second time, the get token(authorization) requests are fired again, which is not needed. I need to call the get token requests, only on expiry.

I'm thinking of setting a variable to false, if the token is not expired and putting the get token requests under an if controller. But how do I set a variable in if controller?

If you have any other ways of achieving this, please do suggest.

TIA

Comment: Ideally, you shall request a token when it's is expired. What's the message you get when a token is expired?

Comment: The token request doesn't say anything anything regarding the expiry. It just returns the token. When I use the token in the subsequent Http requests, if they return 401, that means the token is expired.

Comment: Just updated the answer to check the response code `401` instead of the response message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a flag to check the token expiry. e.g. `isTokenExpired`
2. Define the variable in the [User Defiled Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) section and set the value to `true`. This will ensure token request is fired for the first time.
3. Add an [IF Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to the token request and check the condition `${tokenExpired}`. Set the flag to `false` when a token is created successfully. `vars.put("tokenExpired","false")`

[image]

4. Add a [JSR223 Postprocessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to the top level and check the response code `401` for the token expiry response. If the token is expired, set the flag `isTokenExpired` to `true` and redirect the thread to the next iteration immediately `ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD` .

[image]

```
String responseCode=prev.getResponseCode()


if (responseCode.equals("401")) {
    log.info("Token is expired ")
    vars.put("tokenExpired","true")
    ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Janesh Kodikara. I have a few follow up questions, In the step 3 mentioned, where do I set the isTokenExpired to false, should I use postprocessors or something else, and what can be done if I do not want to go to the next iteration on expiry, but just to get the token and continue from where the http requests failed saying 401. Sorry, if my questions sound dumb. I'm a noob to jmeter. TIA.

Comment: You may request a token from the JSR223 Post Processor itself to continue from where you stopped. I cannot see a quick solution to jumping from the top and resume requests from where it was stopped.

Comment: I'll try to figure that out. Btw what is the script language you used in JSR223 post processor, is it beanshell?

Comment: I am using [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html). Groovy is the recommended scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

> if I run the test plan again immediately(not iterating)

If you run the test plan 2nd time it means that your `tokenGenerationTime` variable gets a new value of the current timestamp equal to the start time of 2nd execution.

If you want to be able to run your test plan 2nd time within 1 hour without firing the token generation request you can consider writing the `tokenGenerationTime` into a file using i.e. [__StringToFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringToFile) function and read it from the file on 2nd and other test executions using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) or if your logic is more complex you can go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and implement whatever you want there

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)